# How can upload image to server with Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

In my application, I want to upload image to the server and for this, I used **Retrofit2**.

I write the below codes, but after upload the image shows me a server error!
**This error is:** Media field is empty, please fill this!

This error is from my server and says to me the media field is empty!

**My API codes:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("/media")
fun uploadImage(
    @Header(AUTHORIZATION) auth: String, @Header(ACCEPT) accept: String, @Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
    @PartMap map: LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody>
): Single<Response<ResponseModelUploadImage>>
```

**My Activity codes:**

```
            var requestBody: RequestBody
            var body: MultipartBody.Part
            val mapRequestBody = LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody>()

            Log.e("filePath",uploadNaturalImageFile.toString())

            requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), uploadNaturalImageFile);
            mapRequestBody.put("media\"; media=\"" + uploadNaturalImageFile.name, requestBody);

            presenter.callUploadImage(userToken, APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_JSON, mapRequestBody)
```

But when upload this image with Postman, everything is OK and doesn't have any problem!

**Postman request image:**
[image]

**UPDATE :** I see my log and show me `name=media`, but server again media is empty!
**My logcat messages:**

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="JPEG_20201108_1623315560915977415445829.jpg"
```

Why show me this error? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your RetrofitService.java

```
@Multipart
@POST("/app/uploadFile.do")
Call<JsonObject> uploadFile(@PartMap() LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> partMap, @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> names);
```

and in your activity,

```
public static void fileUpload (File file) {

    Log.d(TAG, "file===" + file.getName());

    RequestBody requestBody;
    MultipartBody.Part body;
    LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> mapRequestBody = new LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody>();
    List<MultipartBody.Part> arrBody = new ArrayList<>();


    requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    mapRequestBody.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName(), requestBody);
    mapRequestBody.put("test", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "gogogogogogogog"));


    body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileName", file.getName(), requestBody);
    arrBody.add(body);


    Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitImg.getInstance().getService().uploadFile(mapRequestBody, arrBody);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

          if (response.body() != null) {

          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
          Log.e(TAG + "Err", t.getMessage());
      }
    });

}
```

**UPDATA : I found other example**

```
@POST("my/files/photo/")
Call<FileUploadResponse> uploadPhoto(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                             @Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                             @Body MultipartBody body);
```

and

```
ApiClient.ApiInterface client = ApiClient.getClient();
File file = new File(getPathFromUri(fileUri));
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), file);
MultipartBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().addFormDataPart("file-type", "profile")
                   .addFormDataPart("photo", "image.png", fileBody)
                   .build();
client.uploadPhoto("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + body.boundary(),
                       PrefManager.getInstance().getToken(), body);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224352/discussion-on-answer-by-s-t-how-can-upload-image-to-server-with-retrofit-on-andr).

Comment: can you add the Kotlin version please?